# Inserting data at a specific index in a class list C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, csv

I have a class called `cPoint`

```
public class cPoint
{
  public string point;
  public string time;
  public double xPoint;
  public double yPoint;
  public string csv;
  public string barcode;
  public double meanX;
  public double meanY;
}
```

And a global list `sorted`. I parse an XML file then add the data to:

```
cPoint Point = new cPoint();
Point.time = endTime;
Point.point = location;
Point.xPoint = Convert.ToDouble(xOffset);
Point.yPoint = Convert.ToDouble(yOffset);
Point.barcode = panelSerNo;
sorted.Sort((x, y) => x.point.CompareTo(y.point));
Point.csv = endTime + "," + panelSerNo + "," + location + "," + xOffset + "," + yOffset;
sorted.Add(Point);
```

Eventually I do some maths calculations with the list, then add those results to sorted.csv based on user input:

```
 if (aoiFlag == true) 
 {
   sorted.Last(n => n.point == name).csv += "," + sixSigx + "," + sixSigy;
 }
```

This prints a csv file:
[image]

Now what I would like to do, is when `sorted` is fully populated and the user input is established, before writing to the file go back to the first 4 elements of the sorted list and add data to the csv (sorted.csv?)part of each class in those 4 elements. My goal is to add the extra text (the text in red) to the output. I've done some research on how to do this but because `sorted` is a list of classes, it's throwing me off how to use something like `List.Insert`. I have previous C experience but this is my first C# project (OOP is a different world!). Any help would be great cos I'm a newbie.

Cheers

Comment: So you want to update the `csv` property of the first 4 elements ?

Comment: Yes, I just thought that I'd add some background information to avoid confusion

Comment: You can access the element by index. You can do `sorted[0].csv += "USL(um)" + "," + "70";` I don't really know where are you reading those 8 values from. But a simple for loop from 0 to 3 would work like a charm.

Comment: Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I posted in the comments above, you need to do a simple for loop to access the elements inside a list (Whether class elements or primitive types):

```
for(int i =0; i < 4; i++)
{
   // Change this static data to read it from somewhere
   // like += results[i] + "," + pass[i];
   sorted[i].csv += "USL(um)" + "," + "70";
}
```

Or if you have static data, either put them inside an array of strings or write 4 duplicates lines (not recommended):

```
sorted[0].csv += "USL(um)" + "," + "70";
sorted[1].csv += /* next line data */;
sorted[2].csv += /* next line data */;
sorted[3].csv += /* next line data */;
```

Answer (score 3):

To change any element in list you can use it like C's array,

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    sorted[i].csv += ",USL(um),70"
}
```

To insert a new element into specific index of a list use `Insert(index, value)` method. This method insert a new element in index position and shift right rest of elements.

```
sorted.Insert(i, myPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ElementAt` LINQ method to access a certain element in a list.

```
var firstElement = sorted.ElementAt(0);
firstElement.Result = "USL (µm)";

var secondElement = sorted.ElementAt(1);
// ...
```